# laser_assembler with PointCloud2

Tags: ros, laser-assembler, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if we can ever work using laser_assembler with PointCloud2 data type. Last time I tried and so does mention in the the tutorial, laser_assemble is using PointCloud, instead of PointCloud2. If it is only meant to be compatible with only PointCloud, this seems not quite interesting because PointCloud type will be deprecated at some point in time later. There is another [thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/9909/is-there-a-laser-assembler-that-produces) asking similar question, but, it was rather old information.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27753/laser_assembler-with-pointcloud2/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made my own because one did not exist. I wrote it up quickly, so it might not be fully optimized, but it's reliable and it works just fine. Instead of calling a service to receive the assembled cloud, this publishes the assembled cloud on every callback. For this reason, it's less efficient than ROS's `laser_assembler`, but it serves my purpose just fine. It also provides a service that allows you to pause the assembler so that you can view a cloud without it being updated. You can find the code [here](http://pastebin.com/gsmCGweU).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hali19](https://answers.ros.org/users/9076/hali19/) on 2013-11-21**:
Thanks a lot! It works!